# How to get frames count from avi file ? and go to specific frames?

Tags: c#, frames

Like my question, Can anybody tell me how to get frames count from avi file? and go to specific frames and extract to screen in c# .

Comment: Isn't an avi file a wrapper for a variety of underlying formats, each of which would need their own codec to play? If so, I'm not sure this is trivial to achieve.

Comment: DirectShow? Seems like this is [not as simple as it might be](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/forums/forum/460697/topic/3841029).

Answer (score 0):

In the AVI header there a **dwTotalFrames** count which holds the total number of frames.

See the documentation here:

http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf

Page 8

Have a look at this C# header parser:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/riffparser.aspx